# How to find out index of nth empty row in Excel?

Tags: excel

Given a column of numbers in `A:A`

```
11
22

33
44

55
```

I can find out that index of first empty row is 3 by `=MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(A:A),0)`

How can I change that formula to find out that index of second empty row is 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following for your input data in cell `C1`:

```
=FILTER(ROW(A1:A7), ISNUMBER(XMATCH(ISBLANK(A1:A7), TRUE)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample output file]

If you want only the 2nd blank or nth-empty in the more general case, then:

```
=SMALL(FILTER(ROW(A1:A7), ISNUMBER(XMATCH(ISBLANK(A1:A7), TRUE))),2)
```

You can also use the following alternative to the first formula:

```
=FILTER(IF(A1:A7="",ROW(A1:A7)), IF(A1:A7="",ROW(A1:A7))<>FALSE)
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetition:

```
=LET(x, IF(A1:A7="",ROW(A1:A7)), FILTER(x, x<>FALSE))
```